# Can I subdivide a mesh nonuniformly until a maximum face area is achieved?

Tags: geometry, subdivision-surface

I want a sphere which I can model a planet on. I want any given area to have roughly the same resolution. A UV sphere concentrates geometry at the poles.

My [first solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/314085) was clunky and problematic.

Ideally, I would like to apply some sort of subdivision operation with the following logic:

> For each face: if its area exceeds a given maximum of A units, subdivide that face (across its longest dimension, so the tendency is to squares rather than noodles).
>
> Reposition the new vertices to maintain consistent overall curvature.
>
> Keep doing this until all faces have an area of less than A.

Does such an operation exist?

Comment: If you don't want poles, maybe begin with a subdivided cube (with Smoothness at 1 to make it spherical)?

Comment: Do you know about icospheres?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an icosphere.

OR

2. Subdivide the sphere unevenly, then use the remesh function from the mesh data tab.

Comment: an icosphere will produce shading issues or do I miss something?

Comment: @lemon The OP wants a dense even sphere for a planet. Would you not use an icosphere? What shading issues?

Comment: ok, forget it, sorry. Dense icosphere is ok, but subdivided low density is not.

Comment: Suppose I want to do this for a general mesh?

Comment: Then you use the second method.